# I can't figure this out the System call "read" function in c. ( K&R c language book)

Tags: c, unix, filesystems, system-calls

i'm new to C and this is even my first question to ask in "stackoverflow.com"
If i'm doing something unpleasant, plz correct me :)

SO, what i'm trying to understand is what is the real process of "read function".
Let me specify my question in detail while explaining what i'm experimenting.
Basic concept of my small program is that copy a file into screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1000

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{ 
        int fd, n;
        char buf[BUF_SIZE];
        char *name;
        name = argv[1];

        fd = open(name, O_RDWR, 0);

//------------whith while loop -----------------------
        //while( (n = read( fd, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0 )
        //       {
        //              printf("?");
        //
        //              write(1, buf, n);
        //              printf("??");
        //       }

// ------------without while loop ----------------

              n = read( fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
                printf("?");
                write(1, buf, n);
                printf("??");

        return 0;
}
```

**First**,(1) my question was "why do i need while loop for read() ?

my understanding was that after i call the system call "read()" (i'm not sure if it's real system call or just function provided by C library which will call the real systemcall),
it now gets buf[] and BUF_SIZE to fill out and it happened at one call. But then again, there should be a reason to put while loop..

But **The result** of both are the same displaying the exact same content of file.

**Second**, (2) my question was if the system call "read" gets called several time till end of file, then how many time can get inside while loop calling "write function" (that's why i put printf("?") ).

**But the result** stroke ...
It ignored my printf function whether it's called before "write" or after.

I think there is very huge concept i'm missing.. I hope someone would really help me out :)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You also need a loop around `write`.

Comment: Don't mix buffered output calls (such as `printf()`) with unbuffered calls (such as `write()`). Results from doing so are not well-defined.

Comment: @KerrekSB you mean the one inside while loop which i put commented?.

Comment: There are really two questions here, not one. For the future, it's considered good etiquette on StackOverflow to have one question to each, well, question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you! That's something that i didn't take into account and now i can address the concept of buffered and unbuffered function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, well step by step. The `read` function you're calling is actually a wrapper to a low level system cal probably called `sys_read`. Usually the C standard library provide wrappers to all system calls.

#### Why a `while` loop?

`read` function returns the number of bytes read by the function. This isn't necessary all the bytes the file contains. You need a while loop to keep reading the file in order to be able to completely process it. If both versions worked (with and without loops) is probably (most definitely) because the file is small and you were able to store it completely in the array but what abaut 1GB file?

`write` function behaves more or less the same and you sometimes you need a `while` loop too to completely dump a buffer in a file.

#### Why `printf` doesn't print?

`printf` function usually buffer the data before dumping it to the console. Normally it wait until it sees an *end of line* character before dumping it so if you change your code to:  `printf("??\n");` you will probably see it on the screen.

One more thing, of course there's a lot more technical stuff about these (**a lot**) so if you really want to learn about `read` function (and any other Unix system call or C library function) you can consult the manual pages 2 and 3 (2 for system calls and 3 for library functions). `read` for example is documented in [`read(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read). And if you want to go even deeper, go grab the source code to see how the *really* work :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you need a loop around `write`. The operating system may choose to write less than your full buffer, or may tell you to retry (with a return code such as `EINTR`). Even if simple testing with small output buffers doesn't reveal these cases doesn't mean they don't exist.
2. Don't mix buffered output calls (such as `printf`) with unbuffered output (such as `write()`). `printf`'s output is buffered, so it won't be emitted until you explicitly flush it, or until there's a newline in the contents, or such time as the buffer is full.

Comment: Thank you sir, i've selected the answer above as it seems well organised. However, i really appreciate your effort to reply. I'll get to know more about buffered and unbuffered concept.